# In iOS, CallKit is not shown to the user, when application is in background or terminated state

Tags: ios, voip, callkit

In iOS, Callkit is not working in background/ in the terminated state. I am receiving VoIP notification and triggering the CallKit to show the user call.

But app seems to be terminated when I trigger callkit in terminated state and app seems to show callkit in background, if the app is in background state.

When the app is in background state and I receive a VoIP notification, the callkit is called, but I can see the call ringing screen, only if I click on the app icon.

Can anyone have any idea to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

We sorted out the issue. 

Root cause: When we receive VoIP push in App background/terminated state, we should notify the CallKit without changing the thread and initiate background task. If you change the thread, the CallKit will not work as expected.

Comment: Could you please be more specific ? I am facing the same issue :-/